# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'

Tags: python, keras, modulenotfounderror

```
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
```

I'm getting following error:

```
----> 1 from rl.agents import DQNAgent

File c:\.....\rl\agents\__init__.py:2
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from .dqn import DQNAgent, NAFAgent, ContinuousDQNAgent
      

File c:\.....\rl\agents\dqn.py:8
      5 from keras.models import Model
      6 from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Layer, Dense
----> 8 from rl.core import Agent
      9 from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy, GreedyQPolicy
     10 from rl.util import *

File c:\.....\rl\core.py:8
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from keras.callbacks import History
----> 8 from rl.callbacks import (
      9     CallbackList,
     10     TestLogger,
     11     TrainEpisodeLogger,
     12     TrainIntervalLogger,
     13     Visualizer
     14 )
     17 class Agent(object):
     18     """Abstract base class for all implemented agents.
     19 
     20     Each agent interacts with the environment (as defined by the `Env` class) by first observing the
   (...)
     38         processor (`Processor` instance): See [Processor](#processor) for details.
     39     """

File c:\.....\rl\callbacks.py:12
     10 from keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION
     11 from keras.callbacks import Callback as KerasCallback, CallbackList as KerasCallbackList
---> 12 from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
     15 class Callback(KerasCallback):
     16     def _set_env(self, env):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'
```

I could see another similar question being raised [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/126268/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-keras-utils-generic-utils?newreg=9c89d4ae9f2a4c14bf28c568160a557d).

I would like to know if there is a solution that does not ask me to change the source files. If so, should I create an Issue on GitHub? Or am I making some fundamental mistake?

Comment: You are using a version of Keras that is not compatible with the rl library

Comment: ```pip install keras -U```

This gives me the following error and thus I have to go back to earlier version. 

```ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires keras<2.14,>=2.13.1, but you have keras 2.15.0 which is incompatible.```